# Arch Linux cannot boot

Tags: boot, arch-linux

I have a WD My Passport USB 3.0 500 GB hard disk
I have successfully installed various OSes like Ubuntu, Pinguy, Mint etc. but so far I'm unsuccessful in installing Arch Linux.

I used the net install CD and the installation is smooth, only when I reboot and boot off my hard disk I get an error saying "cannot find filep" (something along similar lines) and when I try booting again (without a reboot), I get:
`error 18 and and boot cylindar size exceeds maximum value type` error.

I tried `rootdelay=8` from the Beginners' Guide on the Arch Wiki and after scavenging through forums even enabled usb in the hook file while installing.

I still can't boot.

If it's of any further help I have dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my laptop. My usb is partitioned as following:
[image]

here is my menu.lst http://pastebin.com/FdAiHnXZ

and the errors
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and including the _exact_ errors you see when you try and boot would also be helpful.

Comment: my menu.lst http://pastebin.com/FdAiHnXZ

Answer (score 2):

Grub can't read past a certain point, it looks like [8 gigs](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_13.html) on most machines.  You'll have to move the partition with your `/boot` to the front of the drive.  I've heard (and followed) suggestions to make it a separate partition for this reason.

---

As for the error 15, the kernel name might be wrong, go into a recovery shell or rescue disc and check the name (usually just vmlinuz), then edit the menu.lst to match.  I seem to recall an ill-advised update doing this to my arch machine once, maybe you got a similarly broken snapshot.

Comment: My arch box has a /boot/vmlinuz-linux file, and a symbolic link /boot/vmlinuz26 pointing to it.  I run "pacman -Syu" about every week, so its relatively up-to-date.

Comment: I don't remember when the transition happened, but machines where Grub can't read past 8GB would be getting old in the tooth and probably not running Windows 7.

Comment: I have arch partition (with /boot) after ~80GB of unallocated space. I use GRUB 2 though.

Comment: still no use all names are correct. when u updare my grub on the existing ubuntu on laptop it shows up arch and boots through it effortlesslesy

Answer (score -1):

Please read [about the updates to the kernel package and filenames.](https://www.archlinux.org/news/changes-to-kernel-package-and-filenames/) You need to edit your menu.lst accordingly - you can do that on the fly while booting with grubs edit function).

Comment: its correct.. can u tmme wat to edit